# Разница дат, PHP

Tags: unixtimestamp, php

Добрый вечер. Уважаемые подскажите принцип для PHP, как в получить все даты в промежутке между двумя даными?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dates = array();
$time1 = time()-(15 * 86400); // 15 дней назад
$time2 = time();

$t = $time1;
do{
  $dates[] = date('d.m.Y', $t);
  $t += 86400;
  } while ($t < $time2);

print_r($dates);
```

Для получения таймстампа из даты пользуемся [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Благодарю. Метод пришел к самому правда сложнее и не такой лаконичный. :)

Comment: С таким вот подходом очень здорово выстрелить себе в ногу в момент перевода времени. 

Просто сам так же делал и напоролся на грабли

Answer (score 2):

```
$start = new DateTime(); 
$end = new DateTime('2012-01-01'); 
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('r')."\n";
}
```